# How to create an Input Box in c# uwp that automatically do something?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to create an input box (without buttons) that wait an input from the user (tipically numbers) and, when the lenght is equal to 24, it calls another function to do something.

I already create one but using a confirm button: 
in mainpage.xaml.cs

```
public void WaitingInput()
    {
        string text = InputTextDialogAsync();
        DoSomething(text);
    }

private void InputTextDialogAsync()
    {
        TextBox inputTextBox = new TextBox();
        inputTextBox.AcceptsReturn = false;
        inputTextBox.Height = 32;
        inputTextBox.Width = 300;
        ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog();
        dialog.Content = inputTextBox;
        dialog.Title = "Input Reader";
        dialog.IsPrimaryButtonEnabled = true;
        dialog.IsSecondaryButtonEnabled = false;
        dialog.PrimaryButtonText = "Ok";
        if (await dialog.ShowAsync() == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
            return inputTextBox.Text;
        else
            return "";
    }
```

it creates what I want but using the ok button to confirm.

```
public void DoSomething (string text) {
   if (text.length < 24) {
       WaitingInput();
       return;
   }
   // Do Something with text input ...

}
```

I tryed with inputTextBox.TextChanging but, even if the input text satisfied the requirements (length == 24) when it finishes the load of the page the inputText appears again...

I'm missing something and maybe it exists a better solution to do that.

---- UPDATE:
Now I'm able to hide the contentdialog box but when you try to insert this input text "123456789012345678901234" I get an error saying that I cannot open more than one content dialog even if I put the Hide function

mainpage.xaml.cs

```
namespace App1
{

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    ContentDialog dialogInput = new ContentDialog();
    TextBox inputBox = new TextBox();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WaitingInput();
    }

    public async void WaitingInput()
    {
        inputBox.AcceptsReturn = false;
        inputBox.Height = 32;
        inputBox.Width = 300;
        inputBox.TextChanging += TextChangingHandler;
        dialogInput.Content = inputBox;
        dialogInput.Title = "Input Reader";
        dialogInput.IsPrimaryButtonEnabled = false;
        dialogInput.IsSecondaryButtonEnabled = false;
        dialogInput.PrimaryButtonText = "";
        await dialogInput.ShowAsync();
    }

    private void TextChangingHandler(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender.Text.Length < 24)
        {
            return;
        }
        dialogInput.Hide();
        DoSomething(sender.Text);
    }


    private async void DoSomething(string inputTextUSER)
    {
        if (inputTextUSER == "123456789012345678901234")
        {
            WaitingInput();
            return;
        }
        inputText.Text = inputTextUSER;
        await Task.Delay(3000);
    }
}
```

}

mainPage.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Page_Loaded"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="inputText" Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsReadOnly="True" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" RequestedTheme="Default" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" IsTextPredictionEnabled="False" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" BorderBrush="Black" Width="592" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Background="Transparent" Height="45" Margin="0,50,0,0" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "appears again"?

Comment: basically, after // Do Something with text input ... the main page load everything but the content dialog is always on top and I cannot interact with main page elements

Comment: So your issue is that the dialog isn't closed?

Comment: more or less yes

Comment: How do you call `WaitingInput()` or `DoSomething()` and from where? They seem to call each other.

Comment: both are in mainpage...basically if the input text does not match some requirements, I have to show again the content dialog box. Hope is it clear now?

Comment: Ok I update the question adding a working example with some progresses

Comment: @mm8 have you an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think OnTextChanging() is the way to go if I understand your requirements correctly.

Here is some code... but understand that there are likely other scenarios that should be accounted for... what about pasting data in that is longer than 24?  validation on input?  how to close the window if there are no buttons and user wants to back out (esc works, but is that good design)? etc. etc.  I'm also not getting into MVVM or other concepts like that.  There is also no exception handling in this code.

You should be able to modify to your liking.

Input Text Dialog control:

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="App1.InputTextDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="TITLE">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox AcceptsReturn="False" Height="32" Width="300" TextChanging="OnTextChanging" />
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```

code behind:

```
public sealed partial class InputTextDialog : ContentDialog
{
    public event EventHandler<EnteredTextArgs> OnValueEntered;
    public InputTextDialog()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnTextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        if (sender.Text.Length == 24)
        {
            OnValueEntered?.Invoke(this, new EnteredTextArgs() { EnteredText = sender.Text });
            sender.Text = string.Empty;
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

args class:

```
public class EnteredTextArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string EnteredText { get; set; }
}
```

main page:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Show Dialog" Click="OnShowClick" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtblockResult" />
</StackPanel>
```

main page code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    InputTextDialog dialog = new InputTextDialog();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dialog.OnValueEntered += Dialog_OnValueEntered;
    }

    private void Dialog_OnValueEntered(object sender, EnteredTextArgs e)
    {
        txtblockResult.Text = e.EnteredText;
    }

    private async void OnShowClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

****UPDATE****
OK.  Based on your most recent update, I think this is what you intended... but without knowing the full requirements, this seems like it needs some work.  Good luck!

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        ContentDialog dialogInput = new ContentDialog();
        TextBox inputBox = new TextBox();

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            //you only want to call this once... not each time you show the dialog
            Setup();
            Loaded += Page_Loaded;
        }

        public void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           WaitingInput();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// initializes the dialog and its child - the textbox
        /// </summary>
        private void Setup()
        {
            inputBox.AcceptsReturn = false;
            inputBox.Height = 32;
            inputBox.Width = 300;
            inputBox.TextChanging += TextChangingHandler;
            dialogInput.Content = inputBox;
            dialogInput.Title = "Input Reader";
            dialogInput.IsPrimaryButtonEnabled = false;
            dialogInput.IsSecondaryButtonEnabled = false;
            dialogInput.PrimaryButtonText = "";
        }

        private void ResetDialog()
        {
            inputBox.Text = string.Empty;
            WaitingInput();
        }

        public async void WaitingInput()
        {
            await dialogInput.ShowAsync();
        }

        private async void TextChangingHandler(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender.Text.Length < 24)
            {
                return;
            }

            dialogInput.Hide();
            await DoSomething(sender.Text);
        }

        private async Task DoSomething(string inputTextUSER)
        {
            if (inputTextUSER == "123456789012345678901234")
            {
                //note: the dialog will not show again.  May as well close the app
                return;
            }
            //show inputted text in textblock
            inputText.Text = inputTextUSER;
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            //after 3 seconds, show the dialog again - unclear requirement
            ResetDialog();
        }

}
```

mainpage.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="inputText" Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsReadOnly="True" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" RequestedTheme="Default" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" IsTextPredictionEnabled="False" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" BorderBrush="Black" Width="592" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Background="Transparent" Height="45" Margin="0,50,0,0" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your answer...I understand your comments but basically this function should be always running on a pc...for this reason there are no buttons to close or other stuff....Please, check my complete example to show you what i'm doing...thanks a lot

Comment: I updated based on what it looks like you're trying to do.